# Access VBA not appending date properly in loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a loop that (among other things) inserts a date and then in each row, adds a month to that date.  It is not appending the first date properly.  The date is a DLookup from a date field in a query, so I think it should work as a date.  And I don't see anything wrong with my SQL statement.  But when this runs the date shows up in the table as 12/30/1899 and if you click on it, it changes to 12:03:34 AM.  It's supposed to be 5/1/15.  Nothing I've tried to get this to work has given me any other results.

Here's my code, please note: there's probably a couple other things wrong with my overall code I'm sure, but I'm focusing on this date problem for now.  Feel free to point out whatever you find, though.

```
Private Sub AmortButton_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim Account As Long: Account = DLookup("[L#]", "qry_info4amort") 'working
Dim StartDate As Date: StartDate = CDate(DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort")) 'NOT WORKING
Dim InterestRate As Double: InterestRate = DLookup("IntCur", "qry_info4amort") 'working
Dim piConstant As Integer: piConstant = DLookup("[P&IConstant]", "qry_info4amort")
Dim UPB             As Currency: UPB = DLookup("UPB", "qry_info4amort")                 'working
Dim tempUPB         As Currency: tempUPB = UPB                                          'working (just to establish variable)
Dim AmortInterest   As Currency: AmortInterest = 0                                      'working (just to establish variable)
Dim AmortPrincipal  As Currency: AmortPrincipal = 0                                     'working (just to establish variable)
Dim Ranking         As Integer: Ranking = 1                                             'working (just to establish variable)
Dim PaymentLoop     As Integer: PaymentLoop = 1                                         'working (just to establish variable)
Dim PaymentNumber   As Integer: PaymentNumber = DLookup("NumPmts", "qry_info4amort")    'working
Dim tempInterest    As Integer: tempInterest = 0                                        'working (just to establish variable)

Do While PaymentLoop <= PaymentNumber                                                   'working

tempInterest = Round(tempUPB * (InterestRate / 12), 2)
tempUPB = Round(tempUPB - (piConstant - tempInterest), 2)
AmortPrincipal = AmortPrincipal + (piConstant - tempInterest)
AmortPrincipal = (piConstant - tempInterest)
AmortInterest = AmortInterest + tempInterest

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_AmortizationTest ([L#],[Payment#],[PaymentDate],[UPB],[Interest],[Principal],[TotalPayment],[InterestRate],[TempUPB],[Ranking]) " & _
             "VALUES (" & Account & "," & PaymentLoop & "," & StartDate & "," & UPB & "," & tempInterest & "," & AmortPrincipal & "," & (tempInterest + AmortPrincipal) & "," & InterestRate & "," & tempUPB & "," & Ranking & ")"

UPB = tempUPB
StartDate = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate)      'NOT WORKING
PaymentLoop = PaymentLoop + 1               'working
Ranking = Ranking + 1                       'working

Loop

MsgBox "Done!"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if `PaidToDate` is of data type Date, retrieve your date as is:

```
StartDate = DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort")
```

If it is a string, CDate or DateValue will do:

```
StartDate = DateValue(DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort"))
```

Second, format a proper string expression for the date when concatenating it into SQL:

```
... PaymentLoop & ",#" & Format(StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#," & UPB ...
```

Comment: Bingo!  FWIW I didn't need to use Format in the SQL string, i guess since it's a date data type all the way through the process.  Just missing those # signs.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CDate()` around your `DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort")` you are probably going to have to pull out the relevant parts piece by piece...

```
StartDate = DateSerial(<year>, <month>, <day>)
```

For example, if `DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort")` returns `05012015` then you could do:

```
StartDate = DateSerial(Mid(DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort"),5,4), Left(DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort"),2), Mid(DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort"),3,2))
```

If the `DLookup("PaidToDate", "qry_info4amort")` returns a value with `/` in it, then you will have to use some `Instr()` functions... [More on that here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php).

Comment: DateSerial will return a string though, and I'm inserting these values into a date field.  Is this a problem?  the DLookup does return / (5/1/15) but I think I can use date part to part this out, maybe?

Comment: @msim `DateSerial` returns a `Date`.

Comment: huh, I'm getting a type mismatch error on it, so I thought that was the issue

Comment: damn, got DateSerial to work in that a MsgBox StartDate gives me the right thing (5/1/2015), but then it still inserts 12/30/1899 into the table